# Error on Hover Panel of Web page"We didn't find any more information about this result."

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, display-template

I added Hover pannel to content search web part display template. I used Default Sharepoint"Item_WebPage_HoverPanel.js" to show web page JS. then I can see the only name of  the page. and on the body part, I get "We didn't find any more information about this result." message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously i dont get the value of "ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Path" in  (if(!Srch.U.w(ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Path) && Srch.U.isSameHost(ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Path, Srch.U.getHostName())) {) this line of Item_Webpage_HoverPanel.Html template. because of thet i get error "We didn't find any more information about this result.". To resolve that error i set the value of "ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Path".like below :ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Path = ctx.CurrentItem.Path; Nor Hover Pannel is working good.